Hamilton-Jacobi equation for a spring pendulum
Consider a system of a mass $m_1$ attached to a (massless) spring of length $l_1$, that stretches vertically (only) by a length $u$ and has spring constant $k$, pivoted to the ceiling and another mass $m_2$ attached to mass $m_1$ by a (massless) string of length $l_2$. The mass $m_2$ makes an angle $\theta$ with the vertical direction (we'll consider it the $\hat{y}$ direction, and $\hat{x}$ will be the horizontal direction). The baseline for zero potential energy will be defined at the pivot point of the spring at the ceiling.
We find the Hamiltonian to be:
$$\begin{align}& H = \frac{(m_1+m_2) P_{\theta}^2}{2 m_2 l_2^2(m_1 + m_2 \cos^2( \theta))} \\&+ \frac{P_u^2}{2 (m_1 + m_2 \cos^2( \theta))} + \frac{\sin(\theta) P_{\theta} P_u}{l_2 (m_1+m_2 \cos^2(\theta))}\\& +\frac{1}{2}ku^2 - m_2 g (l_1 + u + l_2 \cos(\theta))\end{align}$$
Now using the Hamilton-Jacobi equation for this system:
$$ H \left(u, \theta , \frac{\partial S}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta}, t \right) + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = 0$$
where:
$$ P_{\theta} \longrightarrow \frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta} , P_{u} \longrightarrow \frac{\partial S}{\partial u}$$
we can write:
$$  f(\theta) \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 + g(\theta) \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial u} \right)^2 + l(\theta) \frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta} 
 \frac{\partial S}{\partial u} +\frac{1}{2}ku^2 - m_2 g (l_1 + u + l_2 \cos(\theta)) + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = 0$$
How should I go about solving this sort of "coupled" partial differential equation?

It's not a coupled PDE, it's a first order, fully nonlinear PDE that can be handled by the method of characteristics.

Sorry, I didn't mean coupled in a rigorous sense, only because the $\frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial S}{\partial u}$ term is there.
